# temporary file location when using tmpfile() in C

Tags: c, linux, posix, glibc, temporary-files

`$ man tmpfile` says

> The  standard does not specify the directory that tmpfile() will use.
>   Glibc will try the path prefix P_tmpdir defined in `<stdio.h>`, and if
>   that fails the directory /tmp.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 x86_64, gcc and libc BTW.

So when I try to create temporary file using using tmpfile(), I can't see any temporary file in /tmp. ( I can see `# define P_tmpdir    "/tmp"` in stdio.h). This is the code snippet I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *tmp;

    tmp = tmpfile();                            // Where's this file?
    scanf("%*d");

    return 0;
}
```

`$ ./tmpfile`
Now while scanf is waiting for the next (redundant) input I should have been able to see a temporary file in /tmp. But I can't. So Where does exactly this tmpfile get created?

Comment: Did you check the current work directory?

Comment: @alk - Earlier I didn't but now I did. And no there's no temporary file. Actually I am glad that there's no tmpfile in PWD as it would have contradict the manual. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the file entry in the directory is deleted directly. On POSIX systems the file itself remains valid after deletion, as long as you have an open file descriptor to it. (In your case hidden in the `FILE*` return value.)

With that technique, nobody can sneak in and open that file, it is only accessible through your variable `tmp`.

Comment: "With that technique, nobody can sneak in and open that file, it is only accessible through your variable tmp" - This is wrong in the general case - at least on Linux the file can still be reopened, using /proc/$pid/fd. See also e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98700/288001

Answer (score 7):

Compiling your code and running it through `strace` reveals the file's location and name:

```
$ ./a.out
execve("./main", ["./main"], [/* 31 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xe0c000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c51a000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=103425, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 103425, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f038c500000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\357\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1603600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3717176, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f038bf71000
mprotect(0x7f038c0f3000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f038c2f3000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x182000) = 0x7f038c2f3000
mmap(0x7f038c2f8000, 18488, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c2f8000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c4ff000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c4fe000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c4fd000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f038c4fe700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f038c2f3000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f038c51c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f038c500000, 103425)          = 0
stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 25957
open("/tmp/tmpfflAlKG", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
unlink("/tmp/tmpfflAlKG")               = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
brk(0)                                  = 0xe0c000
brk(0xe2d000)                           = 0xe2d000
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c519000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f038c518000
read(0, alk
"alk\n", 1024)                  = 4
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

`"/tmp/tmpfflAlKG"` gets created via `open()`

```
open("/tmp/tmpfflAlKG", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
```

and then immediatly gets `unlink()`

```
unlink("/tmp/tmpfflAlKG")               = 0
```

so the visible directory entry disappears.

As still open to the process the file itself stays valid for the process until the process `close()`s it. The latter happens implicitly via the call to `exit_group()`:

```
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see the name of file an can verify what Jens Gustedt answered, as I can see `unlink()` call too. Thanks for `strace`.

Comment: I'd rather suggest `strace -e open`. Temp file can't escape the `open()` syscall anyway.

Comment: Note that newer glibc versions will employ the `O_TMPFILE` flag first, which creates an unnamed inode in the directory’s file system with no links to it, and only fall back to regular `open`+`unlink` if that doesn’t work (e. g. because the file system doesn’t support it).

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile:

> On some implementations (e.g. Linux), this function actually creates, opens, and immediately deletes the file from the file system: as long as an open file descriptor to a deleted file is held by a program, the file exists, but since it was deleted, its name does not appear in any directory, so that no other process can open it. Once the file descriptor is closed, or once the program terminates (normally or abnormally), the space occupied by the file is reclaimed by the filesystem.
>
> On some implementations (e.g. Windows), elevated privileges are required as the function may create the temporary file in a system directory.

Comment: Not a real answer. The had suited as comment.